# SELinux - workaround using audit2allow?

Tags: security, selinux

I read carefully tutorial and got to explanations on using `audit2allow` which allows access for denied process.
[audit2allow tutorial](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/sect-security-enhanced_linux-fixing_problems-allowing_access_audit2allow)

After reading about `audit2allow` it seems that this tool can always be used no matter what, I can't see that there is mention of any restrictions whatsoever.

So... If `audit2allow` is always allowed it is a kind of workaround for the security.

Right ?

Answer (score 0):

> So... If `audit2allow` is always allowed it is a kind of workaround for
>   the security.

`audit2allow` is **not** ”always allowed”. Here is what happens when you try to run as a non `root` user:

```
[maulinglawns@centos ~]$ audit2allow -a
Error opening config file (Permission denied)
NOTE - using built-in logs: /var/log/audit/audit.log
Error opening /var/log/audit/audit.log (Permission denied)
```

SELinux can be a rather blunt tool sometimes. Think of `audit2allow` as a way to help you generate local modules that will allow certain commands/processes that are blocked by SELinux by default, but that you - as a system administrator - are confident *should* be allowed.

Generating local policies is something that I have done on almost every GNU/Linux server I manage that runs RHEL/CentOS with SELinux in enforced mode (which it should be if it is in production), so it is nothing ”irregular”.

But, as always, do not blindly generate local policies; you have to make sure that the policy you are creating does not allow for something that is **properly** blocked by SELinux.

Also consider [sealert](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sealert), which in my opinion is the currently best tool out there to generate human readable outout from the `audit` logs. With clear instructions on how to generate policies.

Comment: How selinux knows that I am administrator and not a regular user?

Comment: @ransh It doesn't. But only `root` users can insert new policies.

Comment: You need to be root *and* the currently loaded policy needs to allow you to do so